# how to set startup project through coding in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i would like to run a command prompt to run the project and set its startup project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great Idea @Klausbyskov. Here is the code for the Macro. Please, any upvotes to Klaus

[See MSDN VS Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx)

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module RecordingModule
Sub TemporaryMacro()
DTE.ExecuteCommand ("Project.SetasStartUpProject")
End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 4):

You could record a macro and assign it to some combination of keys. I think it would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Using this project https://github.com/ParticularLabs/SetStartupProjects you can include a nuget and then do

```
var startupProjectGuids = new List<string>
{
"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
"22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222"
};
var suoHacker = new SuoHacker();
suoHacker.CreateStartProjectSuoFiles(testSolutionPath, startupProjectGuids);
```